# How to create and implement an alert popup in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to create an alert pop up using rails ? Currently I created an alert view file and the code is described following.I need to implement these error Pop up when a delete button pressed and then it should shows alert view. Can you please help me ?

I need a custom pop up alert. can you give an example for custom pop up and how it implemented ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To add a confirmation on delete button being clicked, use confirm option

```
 <%= link_to "Delete", {:controller => "home", :action => "delete_user"}, :confirm => "Remove this user ?" %>
```

Comment: I need a custom pop up alert. can you give an example for custom pop up and how it implemented ?

Comment: yes you can have the custom popup in a partial, render that partial on the click event

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the alert (conformation pop-up) in the view itself.

Example:

```
    <%= link_to 'Destroy',<path>, :method => :delete,
                                  :confirm => 'Are you sure?'%>
```

On pressing the *Destroy* button a message would pop up asking **Are you sure?**